# Playing audio under lockscreen windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, audio, background

I have a problem with my windows phone 8.1 app. I works fine until i turn on the lock screen, using power button.
It keeps running like its supposed to - but no longer plays the .wav files it´s supposed to.
I have set breakpoints at the methods responsible for playing the sounds, and it seems to run at it should.. Everything else works, all the timer threads and so forth.
I´m using MediaElements to play the sounds, and i have set the properties to

```
snd.AudioCategory = Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.AudioCategory.BackgroundCapableMedia;
```

I have also enabled the background audio task in the Package.appmanifest.

I have tried a lot of stuff including adding this code :

```
Microsoft.Phone.Shell.PhoneApplicationService.Current.ApplicationIdleDetectionMode =
                Microsoft.Phone.Shell.IdleDetectionMode.Enabled;
```

This dosent work however, since it wont recognize the namespace.. Apparently its not used in 8.1 but only 8.0.

This is the method used to play audio :

```
public async void CountDownFromThree()
    {
        MediaElement snd = null;
        snd = SourceGrid.Children.FirstOrDefault(m => (m as MediaElement) != null) as MediaElement;
        if (snd == null)
        {
            snd = new MediaElement();
            SourceGrid.Children.Add(snd);
        }

        StorageFolder folder = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync(@"Assets\SoundsFolder");
        StorageFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync("start-beeps.wav");
        var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
        snd.SetSource(stream, file.ContentType);
        snd.MediaEnded += snd_MediaEnded;
        snd.Play();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. So it seems that in windows phone 8.1, BackgroundMediaPlayer is the way to go. I´ve completely removed all MediaElements - which IMHO having to be part of the visual tree - was pretty wierd afterall.
I found a few resources that helped me, links are below.

http://www.jayway.com/2014/04/24/windows-phone-8-1-for-developers-the-background-media-player/

This codesample helped me a lot, it could be boiled down to very few lines of code for my intended purpose : 
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/BackgroundAudio-63bbc319